# c# VS 2015 Package recently getting null by GetService and Dte(2).GetObject without changes in the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vspackage, vs-extensibility

I'm using the following properties in a VS (2015) Package:

```
    public DTE Dte
    {
        get
        {
            return GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        }
    }

    public ITeamFoundationContextManager TeamExplorer
    {
        get
        {
            return GetService(typeof(ITeamFoundationContextManager)) as ITeamFoundationContextManager;
        }
    }

    public DocumentService DocService
    {
        get
        {
            return Dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.DocumentService")
            as DocumentService;
        }
    }
```

The first one (Dte) seems to work fine and returns a DTE object.
The second (TeamExplorer) does always return **null**,
just like the third property (DocService).

The problem is, that I (and no other) did not check-in any changes since the last release build. The last release build still works on installation, but if I rebuild it, there is the **null**-value issue.

The problem also appears on a co-workers machine.
My Extensibility Tools version is: **1.10.183**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but some mechanism in VS/TFS or myself changed the project's

```
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
```

to 12.0 and changed the assemblies to the lower version (12.x).
Everything worked, after I changed the project file(s) and swapped the assemblies with the 14.x versions.